# Using .replace() to truncate Strings

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm working on a script that will detect the length of certain strings and truncate them to X number of characters.  I've been able to measure the length (ie: determine if they need truncation) and create the truncated value with the `substring()` method but I can't seem to replace the text in the markup with it's new truncated version of itself.

I pretty sure I'm missing something easy, but I can't see it.

```
$('div.horz-sched table td li.odd span.classname a').each(function(){
      if (this.innerText.length > 15) {
          var classname = $(this).text();
          var trimd = classname.substring(0, 15) + "...";
          console.log(trimd);
          $(this).text().replace(classname, trimd);
      }
  });
```

Comment: The duplicate tells what's wrong with the code you have now, but since you're replacing the entire contents, `.replace()` is unnecessary: just do `$(this).text(trimd);`

Comment: Thank you @Juhana. All clear and things are working as they should.  The clarification through the duplicate also makes sense now. Using the replace is one thing, sending it back to the DOM another!